# Why is log shipped database invisible over linked server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, linked-server, log-shipping

We have a lot of linked servers in our SQL Server 2012 instances. While browsing one of those linked servers, I noticed that a log-shipped database is unavailable there.

The database itself is "Standby / Read-Only."

Is it normal for log-shipped databases to be unavailable over linked servers, or is it more likely to be a permissions issue, or could it be something else? I want to query this database using a linked server query.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of my problem is obviously a permission configuration with the linked server entry.  I know this because I set up the same linked server on my local SQL Server instance--using my own login credentials--and was able to see the "Standby / Read-Only" database as I would've normally expected for a standard database.  Clearly, then, there is something about the linked server setup on the other server that is restricting me from viewing one of the databases.